# Interop.Word does not show actual language

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I change language from English (US) to English (UK) in MS Word:

[image]

then click button on Add-in which runs the following code to read language:

```
var appLanguage = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Language;
var docLanguage = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID;
Debug.WriteLine($"Application.Language: {appLanguage.ToString()}");
Debug.WriteLine($"Content.LanguageID: {docLanguage.ToString()}");
```

Output:

```
Application.Language: msoLanguageIDEnglishUS
Content.LanguageID: wdEnglishUS
```

As you can see, it says that language is still English (US).

How correctly read document language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `LanguageID` of the Range class.

```
ActiveDocument.Range.LanguageID
```

Also I'd recommend using the VBA macro recorder in Word to make sure which property should be used when you change the document's language.

Comment: Using VBA macro helped determine that it stores in `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.LanguageID` property.